# Display questions which have not chosen an answer on user profile

Tags: support

How to see all questions which have not chosen an answer on user profile ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Through the user's profile:

When you look at your profile, some questions will be highlighted in green under the **Question** section, **these are the ones you have accepted** an answer for. Those in **white have no accepted answer yet.**

[image]

[image]

---

#### Through search:

Among [a few other things](https://superuser.com/search), search on Super User allows you to select questions without accepted answers:

```
user:<user-id> hasaccepted:0
```

For example, [these would be yours](https://superuser.com/search?q=user:86612%20hasaccepted:0).

Find the user ID in the search field on the profile – it's already filled out.

Comment: You can also do that through search more efficiently. I added that, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @slhck great! always nice to have an alternative method :D

Comment: We can't sort those questions by un-accepted on user profile ?

Comment: @ITFan No. That's not possible.